# How to cancel response in interceptor

Tags: angularjs

How can I cancel the processing of an response if there is an error code passed? 
I want to catch a response with an error code of 500 and prevent my custom service request call from executing its error AND its success function. I want the response to "stay" in the interceptor and not be passed to my custom service success or error callback. How can I achieve this? Is there a best practice of "intercepting" responses and handling them globally?

My **interceptor** has this function:

```
function responseError( response ) {
        switch ( response.status ) {
            case 500:
                // cancel the processing of this response
                // prevent the response from calling error at "HERE" below
                // currently, the error function is called, 
                // even when the response is rejected here
                break;
        }

        return $q.reject( response );
    }
```

My **backend service** has this function:

```
function getJson( url, params ) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http( {
            url: that.host + url,
            method: "GET",
            params: params || {},
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        } ).success( function ( data, status, headers, config ) {
            deferred.resolve( data );
        } ).error( function ( data ) {
            deferred.reject( data );
        } ) ;

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Finally, a **custom service** calls the request:

```
 return BackendService.getJson( "/abc/def", params )
                .then( function ( data ) {
                    return data;
                }, function( data ) {
                    // HERE error function should not be called, if 500
                } );
```

Comment: You *could* use the `responseError` interceptor. In this interceptor you can determine whether or not you can recover from the error you've received and, if so, do the recovery. It's run every time any other http request is rejected. See [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more info. I'm not posting this as an answer because I've never used that API and have no code example for you.

Comment: Thanks. I know it can be done in responseError. The question is how?

Comment: ...Like I said - you try and see if you can recover from the error (that's only logic you can implement). If you can, then you do so and return a `resolve()`. Otherwise return a `reject()`. Any unhandled errors propogate to the top. I don't like @NewDevs idea of just returning the response as-is because then your error falls into a black hole that might be hard to debug.

Comment: I do not want to recover, I want the response to "stay" in the interceptor and not be passed to my custom service success or error callbacks.

Comment: How do you expect to notify the caller that the promise has finished? You *have* to resolve or reject the promise otherwise the caller will be waiting forever until it is resolved or rejected. That's the contract of promises.

Comment: Okay I understand that. What is the use of interceptors then? I need to process the error code again in each error callback, and bail out if it is 500 ?

Comment: The use of interceptors is to transform a request (or response, or error) into some other format before it is passed back to the caller. This could be rewriting urls to `/api/foo` to `SomeOtherServer.com/foo` instead, or it could be taking a request that would otherwise be an error (i.e, 500) and instead allowing it to be treated as a success instead. They provide a single location where you can alter the behaviour of `$http` calls, otherwise you would need to create a custom service for that behaviour, and then use that service everywhere instead of `$http`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got that

Comment: I have a error service. Where should I process error handling with this error service? In the error function of ``backend service`` or in the error functions each of ``custom service``?

Comment: That's another question entirely and you should ask it as such :-)